# Cannot open Settings in Ubuntu 22.04 and gnome-control-center not working

Tags: gnome, 22.04, libraries

I am not able to open Settings in Ubuntu 22.04.
I looked at previous solutions which suggest to install `gnome-control-center`.

However after installing it, I get the following error:
`gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Edited:
I realised the best way was to install libicu.66 directly from deb:\

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

then finally `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center` worked.

Comment: Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libicu70`

Comment: Following up on this. I realised the best way was to install libicu.66 directly from deb:
```wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```
```sudo dpkg -i libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb```


and finally ```sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center``` work